# PHP Logic - echo IMG source using if statement

Tags: php, html, if-statement, logic

I'm struggling to understand why this is not working. Perhaps a simple php logic error?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<img width="160px" src="
<?php 
    if ($output_arr_find_user_id[6] == "UNKNOWN") { 
        echo '/img/icons/devices/Device_Unknown.png';
    } else { 
        echo '/img/icons/devices/Device_6.png'; 
    } ?>
"/>
</div>
```

`$output_arr_find_user_id[6]` is Equal "UNKNOWN".

`$output_arr_find_user_id[6]` Comes from an array, where its value is used elsewhere. When dumped or used as an echo, a value of "UNKNOWN" is given, this proves the value is there.

`var_dump($output_arr_find_user_id[6])` **result:** string(73) "UNKNOWN"

The `else` criteria is currently **NOT** met and "`Device_6.png`" is displayed. Is my code logic wrong?

Would it be more efficient to use else if and provide an "anything else criteria"?

Comment: `$output_arr_find_user_id[6]` depends what that is. Plus, should it be the case, `UNKNOWN` and `unknown` are two different animals.

Comment: I've said `$output_arr_find_user_id[6]` stores: UNKOWN

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's case sensitive, "UNKNOWN" is correct

Comment: After that last edit I'm now entirely confused on what you're describing.  What does "the else criteria is currently not met" even mean?

Comment: well I can't see why you're doing all that logic inside the img src tag. Why not just do it outside of it and then output accordingly

Comment: `"this proves the value is there"` - But doesn't prove anything about potential additional whitespace in the value.  Which wouldn't matter to the browser, but would matter to the `==` operator.

Comment: Could you add the result of  `var_dump($output_arr_find_user_id[6]);`?

Comment: There's no whitespace at all. `var_dump()` = string(73) "UNKNOWN"

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've also tried outside of the img tag :/

Comment: Is it length `7` or `73` in your `var_dump`?

Comment: `if ($output_arr_find_user_id[6] == "UNKNOWN"){ echo the image }else{ echo the other image }` - the "image" being the full `<img ...>` code, not what you're doing now. If that still fails, use error reporting to get to the heart of the matter as well as looking at the HTML source; best I can offer.

Comment: Just to be sure you don't have whitespace and it truly is in caps,  you could try  if (trim(strtoupper($output_arr_find_user_id[6]))) == "UNKNOWN") {    What is the other parameter, if it is not UNKNOWN ? You could flip the if-else to check for that instead

Comment: `if (preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($output_arr_find_user_id[6])) == "UNKNOWN")` works, I guess there was whitespace somewhere? even though this wasn't shown in the dump? strange. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following solution worked for me now because there were some whitespaces that needed to be escaped:

```
if (preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($output_arr_find_user_id[6])) == "UNKNOWN")
```